# ARIMA Forecast - Multiple models

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, arima

I have built a ARIMA model to forecast a particular metric.
Now I want to forecast for two other metrics.
So I have built 2 more models for them respectively.
Thus I have three seperate ARIMA models to forecast three different metrics.
Is there any possibility to combine these models. So that I wil have only one model in the end.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is there any problem in running 3 models? These can be in same script. just add their results.

Comment: With addition of every metric i would have to keep adding up the code which will make it slower . Having one final model to be deployed also i recommended rather than having multiple one's thats why i need this approach.

Answer (score 0):

ARIMA(p,d,q) models are designed specifically to operate on a series of data with a single data point for each interval in the series.  If you want to combine multiple datapoints of different variables into a single model, then you'd probably want something like an Artificial Neural Network.

If you look at the formula for ARMA model:

[image]

you can see that everything is operating on the X_t variable or on the error term (e_t).  So it's not designed for X, Y, and Z.

For an ANN, you can have any number of inputs or outputs.  So multiple input variables can be used for multiple predictions.

[image]

So for example, if you had a time series of temperature data, you might model that with an ARIMA model.  If you have temperature, humidity, and precipitation, then you could use an ANN, as each variable will help make the predictions of the other variables more accurate.